# Windows 8 to Windows 7 Easy Transfer

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

After using Windows 8 Consumer Preview for a while I had to go back to Windows 7 on the same laptop. I wanted an easy way to copy most of my settings and to backup my user folder. I used "Windows Easy Transfer".

Turns out it isn't backwards compatible with Windows 7. "Windows Easy Transfer couldn't open the file"

So how can I restore at least my documents?

Answer (score 1):

While Windows File Transfer isn't retrocompatible, Windows File Sharing is.

Configure your network and sharing settings so that both computers can see each other and access their shared folders, and just copy/paste the files you want to transfer.

Answer (score 0):

**Bad news.** The only way back from a MS `Consumer Preview` is to backup your data and reinstall your original operating system.  *You really should have backed up your system first, so you could have just restored that.*

You have lost most your settings unless you know how to copy them out for each individual application.  EG favourites and bookmarks for you web browsers.